# Strange bug with table in lua

Tags: lua

I'm adding a string to a table in lua. When I use the table in a function the original table is getting altered. I'm only a beginner but I thought that the function could not do that because it is outside of it's scope. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

```
local testTable= {}
testTable.name = {}
testTable.name[1] = "Jon"

print(testTable.name[1])

local function testFunc(a)
    a.name[1] = "Bob"
end

local newTable = testTable

testFunc(newTable)

print(testTable.name[1])
```

I expected the output to be:

```
Jon
Jon
```

The actual output is:

```
Jon
Bob
```

How can the testFunc change the testTable?

Comment: You're passing the reference of the table to your function

Comment: Not what you are asking about, but: The term "scope" refers to the variables that your code can access. In your example, only the function `testFunc` can access the variable `a`, because as a parameter of the function, it is in scope for the function's code, but it doesn't exist outside of it. Technically, your function could also access newTable and testTable variables directly, because they are upvalues (Lua's term for a closure's environment).

Answer (score 0):

You assign testTable's address to newTable, so testTable and newTable point to the same table.
If you want to output be

```
Jon
Jon
```

You should copy the table when you assign newTable.
You can copy the table like this function:

```
function table.copy(old)
    local new = {}
    for k, v in pairs(old) do
        new[k] = v
    end
    return new
end
```

Comment: I believe an "address" isn't a Lua concept, strictly speaking. Tables are copied by reference, all other Lua variables are copied by value. This is similar to the behavior of other languages without pointers, like Javascript or PHP.

Comment: Here is a reference for coping tables. http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable it is worth noting there are deeper copies then the one you suggested

Answer (score 0):

> When I use the table in a function the original table is getting altered. ... I thought that the function could not do that because it is outside of it's scope.

Local variables have their own scope, but tables do not. Two things to remember:

- Variables store references, not values. (This only makes a difference for mutable values.)
- Tables are mutable, i.e., they can be changed internally.

Breaking it down:

```
local newTable = testTable
```

In this line, you're assigning one variable to another, so both variables refer to the same table.

We mutate a table by assigning to an index within that table, so `testFunc` alters whatever `a` (actually `a.name`) refers to. This is handy, because it allows us to write functions that mutate tables that we pass as arguments.

The following function does nothing, like you would expect, because it assigns a new table to the bare name `a` (which happens to be a local variable):

```
local function doNothing(a)
  a = {name = {'Bob'}}
end
```